# How to get autocomplete and suggestions in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to code on Jupyter Notebook on VS Code, but there are no code suggestions nor syntax highlighting!

I am currently running python 3.10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install this extension copy and search in extension `ms-toolsai.jupyter`
2. If suggestion not show then try to press <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The extension is already installed. The weird thing is that it was working perfectly fine till a few day ago. It stopped showing suggestions today only

Comment: @endi__edi reinstall extension.